# Need help expanding space on a debian virtual server

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, web-server

I'm running a vm on vmware and it only had 17gig of space allocated to it, I changed the size of the hard drive in vmware from 17gig to 100gig.

Here is the info for the vm, how can expand the capacity from 17gig to 100gig?

```
Last login: Mon Jul 30 18:33:29 2018
root@observium ~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda1
  VG Name               turnkey
  PV Size               18.57 GiB / not usable 1.41 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              4753
  Free PE               273
  Allocated PE          4480
  PV UUID               AjIer9-K9Ue-vCoB-andJ-Nyjc-M7nq-Grl4dy

root@observium ~# pvdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               turnkey
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               18.57 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              4753
  Alloc PE / Size       4480 / 17.50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       273 / 1.07 GiB
  VG UUID               pMLhIv-btYl-Jel3-VXuu-WnTn-xjzN-W59dUm

root@observium ~# lvs display 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/turnkey/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                turnkey
  LV UUID                xSASQ7-l8Fe-a0kg-ruZa-DnOX-uefh-Fpm3pG
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time tkldev, 2017-06-02 09:02:54 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                17.00 GiB
  Current LE             4352
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/turnkey/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                turnkey
  LV UUID                4d1BKJ-OBvj-iewk-h2Wb-wKWf-7I04-isvqjf
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time tkldev, 2017-06-02 09:02:54 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                512.00 MiB
  Current LE             128
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:1

root@observium ~# lvscan 
  ACTIVE            '/dev/turnkey/root' [17.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/turnkey/swap_1' [512.00 MiB] inherit
root@observium ~# fis  disk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2f250c11

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *    123046 39062500 38939455 18.6G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/turnkey-root: 17 GiB, 18253611008 bytes, 35651584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/turnkey-swap_1: 512 MiB, 536870912 bytes, 1048576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to adjust the side of the partition sda1 to have a larger end.  If you are careful you can just use fdisk, then delete and recreate it.  Just make certain you have the exact same starting sector and type.

After doing that you should be able to run `pvresize /dev/sda1` to expand the space available in LVM.  Then you can resize the logical lvolumes using `lvresize` and finally resize the contained filesystem if ext2/3/4 then you use `resize2fs`.

Comment: What would the commands be to do what you are suggesting? I have never had to do this before so it's my first time.

Comment: `fdisk /dev/turnkey/{lvname}`